How to Display Restart/Stop Blocker Message for a Systemd Service
I'm trying to inform users when a systemd service can't be stopped or restarted because another task is running. While I can log notifications in the journal, I'd prefer a more prominent message on the terminal (TTY). This would make it immediately clear to users that the daemon hasn't been stopped/restarted.
Here's my current service file configuration:
[Unit]
Description=CRM EOD
After=d3_crm.service
BindsTo=d3_crm.service

[Service]
Type=forking
Environment="TOKEN=your_token"
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/crm_eod start
ExecStop=/usr/local/sbin/crm_eod stop
TimeoutSec=0
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

I've tried setting StandardOutput=tty in the service file, but the messages aren't displayed on the TTY. I'd like to log messages to both the journal and the TTY.
